# PDO Invalid parameter number - parameters in comments

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Today I encountered a bug (in PDO) I never saw before, but is kinda obvious when you think about it.

I got the following error:
`Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:`

The query I was using was similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    x
FROM
    y
WHERE
    -- CHECKING IF X = :Z --
    x = :y
AND
    1 = 2
```

Obviously I had more parameters and a longer query.

Why does it give me this error?

Comment: I would combine [your nearly identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415355/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-mixed-named-and-positional-parameters-question/) with this one. Just make a note here that the same thing applies to `?`.

Comment: See my comment on the other question: they result in different errors and deserve - in my humble opinion - separate questions to ease searching.

Comment: Why is this closed? I answered the question myself and this might be important for future reference ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is obvious: PDO disregards comments as such and tries to bind the non-existent variable ':Z'. You can't use parameters in comments in PDO (unless you do bind them).

[There's a similar bug using question marks in comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415355/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-mixed-named-and-positional-parameters-question/)

Comment: Yup, sounds reasonable as PDO would look for the placeholder whether or not it's contained within a comment.

Comment: Wait, did you just post your own question and answer it directly?

Comment: Yes, as this knowledge is useful. It would have saved me half an hour searching for unbound parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize this, and it probably would have bitten me at some point.

Comment: If one doesn't already exist for this, you should report it as a [PHP bug](http://bugs.php.net).