# PDO: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters - question mark in comments

Tags: php, sql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDO Invalid parameter number - parameters in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415314/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-parameters-in-comments)

Today I encountered a bug (in PDO) I never saw before, but is kinda obvious when you think about it.

I got the following error:
`Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`

The query I was using was similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    x
FROM
    y
WHERE
    -- CHECKING IF X = ? --
    x = :y
AND
    1 = 2
```

Obviously I had more parameters and a longer query.

Why does it give me this error?

Comment: I split the two questions and answers on purpose. The underlying bug (or feature, whatever) is the same, but the error it results is different. I assumed this is better for search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is obvious: PDO disregards comments as such and sees the ? as a positional parameter. Removing the ? in your comment solves this problem.

[There's a similar bug using unbound parameters in comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415314/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-parameters-in-comments/)